# C# Possible to auto generate properties based on the known type?

Tags: c#, properties

Its 2022. There has to be a way to do this. Lets say I have an empty class object call MyProperties. I have a current strong type variable on the right side of the statement. Is it possible for VS to see this and that the property doesn't exist and auto create the property based on the strong type of the right hand side of the statement?

```
private class MyProperties 
{
// We are empty so far

}


private void Main()
{
  List<MyProperties> myList = new List<MyProperties>
   {
     Property1 = myStrongTypedClass.AccountNumber,
     Property2 = myStringTypedClass.DoubleList
   // I want it to see that Property 1 or 2 doesn't exist but auto create them based on 
   // the type of AccountNumber and DoubleList.
   }

}

private MyStrongTypedClass

{
  public int AccountNumber {get; set;}
  public decimal Price {get; set;}
  public List<double> DoubleList {get; set}
}
```

Instead of the compiler complaining that MyProperties does not contain a definition for AccountNumber that it will just auto create it

Comment: Yeap there is such a feature in VS. You can create non-existing properties with the help of the light buble. Type of the property will be inferred by the type of the assigned object.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to auto generate without having to click that light bubble for every line? Like I could have 20 properties. It becomes tedious after the 3rd light bubble click

Comment: If you're willing to type these things out once then perhaps it would suit you to use a record instead of a class.. `public record MyStronglyTypedClass(int AccountNumber, decimal Price, List<double> DoubleList)` - to most intents and purposes it's the same as a class, immutable by default but that can be changed, auto provides custom Equals and Hashcode etc, and a constructor that sets all props.. mostly it's quicker to type out. Behaves like your class there-those are properties in the (parentheses), not fields

Comment: Don't forget you can (for years now) type `prop TAB TAB` to insert a property snippet, `ctor` for a constructor, `for` and `forr` for forward and reverse loops etc.. there are loads of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just write it as if it does exist:

```
var mp = new MyProperties;

mp.Hello = "Something";
```

Click on the `Hello` with the wiggly line, and wait for the lightbulb/spanner button to appear near by, or click the lightbulb/spanner in the margin

Choose "Generate Field" or "Generate Property" as you wish...

[image]

Note that it *won't work* in the example you've put in the question:

```
List<MyProperties> myList = new List<MyProperties>
{
    Property1 = myStrongTypedClass.AccountNumber,
    Property2 = myStringTypedClass.DoubleList
    // I want it to see that Property 1 or 2 doesn't exist but auto create them based on 
    // the type of AccountNumber and DoubleList.
}
```

What you've written there is an object initializer that is trying to set properties of List, not a list item initializer trying to add `MyProperties` items to the List.
Trying to set nonexistent `Property1` of a `List<T>` will give you a "doesn't contain a definition for" error but not the option to add it because List is not your class.

Your code will need to look like:

```
List<MyProperties> myList = new List<MyProperties>
{
    new MyProperties() {
        Property1 = myStrongTypedClass.AccountNumber,
        Property2 = myStringTypedClass.DoubleList
    },
    ...
}
```

It's a subtle but important difference

[image]

Lastly, a few other things we can do in 2022 (or even 2017, I think..) is shorten our `new`ing:

```
var myList = new List<MyProperties>
{
    new () {
        Property1 = myStrongTypedClass.AccountNumber,
        Property2 = myStringTypedClass.DoubleList
    },
    ...
}
```

The compiler knows its a `List<MyProperties>` on the right, so you don't need to say it on the left, you don't need to put `()` after the type on the right and you don't need to say `MyProperties` in the item initializer, but you *do* need to use `new()` so C# knows youre trying to make a `MyProperties` and not an anonymous type

Comment: Thanks and nice tip on the shortening of the new. Where can I find more of these tips for 2022?

Comment: They tend to be in ["What's new in C# vXX"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10) style blog posts from the C# dev teams.. Though that's language features rather than IDE features..